# RegEx -- getting rid of double whitespaces?

Tags: c#, regex

I have an app that goes in, replaces "invalid" chars (as defined by my Regex) with a blankspace.  I want it so that if there are 2 or more blank spaces in the filename, to trim one.  For example:

`Deal A & B.txt` after my app runs, would be renamed to `Deal A   B.txt` (3 spaces b/w A and B).  What i want is really this: `Deal A B.txt` (one space between A and B).

I'm trying to determine how to do this--i suppose my app will have to run through all filenames at least once to replace invalid chars and then run through filenames again to get rid of extraneous whitespace.

Can anybody help me with this?
Here is my code currently for replacing the invalid chars:

```
public partial class CleanNames : Form
{
    public CleanNames()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void Sanitizer(List<string> paths)
    {
        string regPattern = (@"[~#&$!%+{}]+");
        string replacement = " ";

        Regex regExPattern = new Regex(regPattern);


        StreamWriter errors = new StreamWriter(@"S:\Testing\Errors.txt", true);
        var filesCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();


        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

           try
            {

              foreach (string files2 in paths)
              {

                string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files2);
                string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(files2);
                string sanitizedFileName = regExPattern.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);
                string sanitized = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFileName);


                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sanitized))
                {
                    DataGridViewRow clean = new DataGridViewRow();
                    clean.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
                    clean.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
                    clean.Cells[1].Value = filenameOnly;
                    clean.Cells[2].Value = sanitizedFileName;
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(clean);

                    System.IO.File.Move(files2, sanitized);
                }

                else
                {
                    if (filesCount.ContainsKey(sanitized))
                    {
                        filesCount[sanitized]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filesCount.Add(sanitized, 1);
                    }
                    string newFileName = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                    System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sanitized),
                    filesCount[sanitized].ToString(),
                    System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sanitized));
                    string newFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(sanitized), newFileName);
                    System.IO.File.Move(files2, newFilePath);
                    sanitized = newFileName;

                    DataGridViewRow clean = new DataGridViewRow();
                    clean.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
                    clean.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
                    clean.Cells[1].Value = filenameOnly;
                    clean.Cells[2].Value = newFileName;

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(clean);

                }




              }
            }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               errors.Write(e);
           }


    }

    private void SanitizeFileNames_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }


}
```

The problem is, that not all files after a rename will have the same amount of blankspaces.  As in, i could have `Deal A&B.txt` which after a rename would become `Deal A B.txt` (1 space b/w A and B--this is fine).  But i will also have files that are like:  `Deal A & B & C.txt` which after a rename is: `Deal A   B   C.txt` (3 spaces between A,B and C--not acceptable).

Does anybody have any ideas/code for how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
        var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\\s{2,}");
        var result = regex.Replace("Some text  with a   lot      of spaces,   and 2\t\ttabs.", " ");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

output is:

```
Some text with a lot of spaces, and 2 tabs.
```

It just replaces any sequence of 2 or more whitespace characters with a single space...

---

Edit:

To clarify, I would just perform this regex right after your existing one:

```
public void Sanitizer(List<string> paths)
{
    string regPattern = (@"[~#&$!%+{}]+");
    string replacement = " ";

    Regex regExPattern = new Regex(regPattern);
    Regex regExPattern2 = new Regex(@"\s{2,}");
```

and:

```
          foreach (string files2 in paths)
          {

            string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files2);
            string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(files2);
            string sanitizedFileName = regExPattern.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);
            sanitizedFileName = regExPattern2.Replace(sanitizedFileName, replacement); // clean up whitespace
            string sanitized = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFileName);
```

I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: does this require a new foreach loop somewhere after i finish "sanitizing" the files?

Comment: @yeahumok Please see my edit above. Just add a 2nd regex after the first, if your existing loop.

Comment: thank you so much!  this worked and it totally makes sense :)  i appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 5):

Do the local equivalent of:

```
s/\s+/ /g;
```

Comment: +1 I like this a bit better than the string replacement solution.  If you're already using Regex's anyways, may as well keep doing it.  This has the advantage of cleaning all whitespace (and in one pass) rather than only hitting spaces.  In practice, I doubt readability or performance will suffer under either solution, and I doubt his text will actually have any other whitespace besides spaces.  But this still feels sensible.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a space to your regPattern.  Any collection of invalid characters and spaces will be replaced with a single space.  You may waste a little bit of time replacing a space with a space, but on the other hand you won't need a second string manipulation call.

Comment: +1: Some of the other solutions use *more* than two loops. Why bother, when you can do the whole job in one loop?

Comment: This makes sense to me -- your regex would be something like `s/[ &*^]+/ /g`, replacing any _series_ of invalid characters (including a space) with a space.

Comment: i gave up this idea because it would miss cases like `na!me$`

Answer (score 1):

After you're done sanitizing it your way, simply replace 2 spaces with 1 space, while 2 spaces exist in the string.

```
while (mystring.Contains("  ")) mystring = mystring.Replace("  "," ");
```

I think that's the right syntax...

Answer (score 1):

you can perform another regex replace after your first one

`@" +" -> " "`

Answer (score 1):

As Fosco said, with formatting:

```
while (mystring.Contains("  ")) mystring = mystring.Replace("  "," ");

//                        ||                                 ||   |
```

Comment: where would i add this statement?  do i need to have another foreach loop or something?

Comment: YOu could add this statement after setting `sanitizedFileName=regExPattern.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);` and use it to replace `sanitizedFileName`.  Of course, there are other places you could put it, though I think that is the best choice.